# Website Hosting with Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, jsp, servlets, web-hosting

I have developed a website with Jsp and Servlets. I want to make it live on a domain that I have purchased already. How can I do that. I would like to prefer Aws. Please guide me with the process.

Comment: In other words, please write my code for me

Comment: Nope, my website is working fine on localhost with Tomcat 9 server.

Comment: Please read through the "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" to understand what is an appropriate question...
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.html) as it supports Tomcat.

If you did not buy your domain through AWS/Route 53 you also need to [point your domain to the nameservers of Route 53](https://serverfault.com/questions/607141/pointing-a-domain-to-aws-route-53)

Within AWS you generally use Route 53 to configure domain names, have a look at [pointing it at your Elastic Beanstalk application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html)

There are other alternatives for hosting your application on AWS but I believe Elastic Beanstalk is good if you are new to AWS. You could package your application into a Docker container and run it on Elastic Beanstalk that way or on ECS (Elastic Container Service).